# Как отправить сообщение в другой канал через SocketMessage Discord

Tags: c#, .net, discord

Юзаю SocketMessage и когда приходит сообщение, хочу повторить его в другом канале, но не понимаю как получить другой канал, чтобы сделать SendMessageAsync

```
if (arg.Content != "")
{
    var guild = _client.GetGuild(5342);
    var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(1180);
                   
    var embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder().WithAuthor($"Автор: {arg.Author.Username}").WithDescription(
        $"**Канал**: {arg.Channel.Name}" +
        $"\n**Сообщение**: {arg.Content}" +
        $"\n \n **Время отправки**: {arg.CreatedAt.AddHours(3)}"
        ).WithColor(Color.Blue);
    await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedBuilder.Build());
}
```

как итог получается что-то такое, но я думаю, что такой метод не правильны, да и он не работает (id обрезал специально внутри получения для наглядности)

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? И почему вы считаете, что это "не правильно"?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Считаю не правильным, потому что делаю привязку к определенному каналу по id, возможно стоит брать id гильдии из сообщения пользователя. Не работает он просто потому, что при обращении к каналу, например `Console.WriteLine(channel.Name);` ничего не выводится в консоль, пустая строка, а также не присылается сообщение

Comment: *к определенному серверу по id,* ошибся в начале

Comment: Об этом стоит писать в вопросе, ибо мы не знаем ваших "хотелок". Ок, что мешает взять из аргументов сервер? Он ведь там есть. Ну а то, что пустой канал, то это либо неверный id, либо у бота нет прав, либо клиент еще не готов (сразу после подключения идет поиск).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мешает взять то, что даже не понимаю как это сделать :( Да и какие могут быть права, на просмотр гильдии?

Comment: Ну чтож вы так, вы ведь программист, а у программиста должен быть развит самый важный навык - поиск. Открываете любимый поисковик, пишете например `discord.net get message guild`, находите например [это](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/621), где прям в пару строк показывают как получить гильдию. Ну а что касается вашего кода, то у меня он например без проблем работает, я лишь вписал свои ID, и вот теперь сами подумайте, как мы можем помочь вам, если с нашей стороны (стороны сообщества) не воспроизводится ваша проблема?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146223/discussion-between-palka-tt-and-evgeniyz).